# After copying setted up Chrome profile to another computer it misses cookies and installed extensions

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, user-profile

I set up a Chrome profile with extension and some authorization cookies. It works good on my computer if I run it from the code. But when I copy this profile to another computer and run it from the code, then all the extensions and cookies of this profile are missing.

Why is it so? And how can I deal with it?

Comment: share you code related to chrome profile and extension. When you say extension do you mean plugins ?

Comment: `string profilePath = Path.GetFullPath($@"C:\WebDriversProfiles\ChromeProfiles\");  
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();  
options.AddArgument("user-data-dir=" + profilePath);  
options.AddArgument("--profile-directory=" + profileName);  
_driver = new ChromeDriver(options);`

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behavior.

See this **code** to launch browser with extension :

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "F:\\Automation\\chromedriver.exe");
            String pathToExtension = "C:\\Users\\USER_DELL_2014_07\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3\\Extensions\\bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp\\2.0_0";
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("load-extension=" + pathToExtension);
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
          }
```

pathToExtension which have value : `C:\\Users\\USER_DELL_2014_07\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3\\Extensions\\bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp\\2.0_0`

This path will be different for second machine because of `USER_DELL_2014_07` this.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer, but I have a little different situation. Look - I copied profile from "...%AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3" to "C://ChromeProfiles/1". After that I ran chromedriver with this profile and setted it up. After that I copied this profile fully to another computer. And when I run it on new computer I see that it is my setted up profile (it has unic name setted up before) but it hasn't got saved cookies and installed extensions.